# Kendo.Grid does not send some data to the controller on "Create" operation

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My Kendo.Grid need to perform CRUD operations on the data on `SAVE CHANGES` click

This is the Grid's definition:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.TicketReportPropertyList)
        .Name("TicketReportPropertyGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(c => c.PropertyName).Title("Property Name").EditorTemplateName("_PropertyNameEditor").Width(900);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Amount).Title("Amount").Format("{0:C}").Width(90);
            columns.Command(c => c.Custom("Delete").Click("DeleteRecord"));
        })
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("Databound").SaveChanges("SaveGrid").Edit("Edit"))
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Create();
            toolbar.Save();
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(c => c.ID);
                model.Field(c => c.PropertyName);
                model.Field(c => c.Amount);
            })
            .Events(events =>
            {
                events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd");
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "TicketReportProperty", Model))
            .Create(create => create.Action("AddTicketReportProperty", "TicketReportProperty"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateTicketReportProperty", "TicketReportProperty"))
            .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("DeleteTicketReportProperty", "TicketReportProperty"))
       )
    )
```

When doing the update, the following method of the controller is invoked:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateTicketReportProperty([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<TicketReportPropertyEntity> ticketReportPropertyList)
    {
        TicketReportPropertyModel model = new TicketReportPropertyModel();
        model = new TicketReportPropertyModel().UpdateTicketReportProperties(ticketReportPropertyList);
        if (!model.Success)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("TicketReportProperty", model.ErrorDescription);
        }
        return Json(new[] { model.TicketReportPropertyList }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

When `Update` is performed, all the data I need is populated inside of `ticketReportPropertyList` parameter and I can update the database

However, when performing a `Create` operation, the controller's method got hit, but `ticketReportPropertyList` is not populated with some of the parameters I need as happen during `Update`.

When adding new record the following method is invoked:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddTicketReportProperty([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<TicketReportPropertyEntity> ticketReportPropertyList)
    {
        TicketReportPropertyModel model = new TicketReportPropertyModel();
        model = new TicketReportPropertyModel().AddTicketReportProperty(ticketReportPropertyList);

        if (!model.Success)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("TicketReportProperty", model.ErrorDescription);
        }
        return Json(new[] { model.TicketReportPropertyList }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

This is TicketReportPropertyEntity:

```
public class TicketReportPropertyEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public int ReportPropertyID { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What parameters are missing? Maybe TicketID & ReportPropertyID since I don't see handling for those.

Comment: Yes, those are missing but amount is not. Here, all the fields should be in the list. They all come inside of the list from UI

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue can be fixed by simply replacing:

```
[Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<TicketReportPropertyEntity> ticketReportPropertyList
```

with

```
TicketReportPropertyEntity ticketReportPropertyList
```

You are not sending a list when creating each row, you are simply sending one object.

Comment: I need to send a List of TicketReportPropertyEntity

Comment: @gene But when you are creating a row, you can only send one

Comment: No, I can add more then one row and send them in the batch. Look at the `Telerik Kendo.Grid()`. It allows to do that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so for creates kendo initializes a new TicketReportPropertyList and then binds values from your columns. So your missing columns will be null. One mechanism to resolve that is to specify `DefaultValue` for those columns in your model definition. The value can come from a field in your model, a set value, value of a hidden, etc. So I typically have a model for the page the grid is displayed on with values for added items. Then I can do:

```
.Model(model =>
 {
    model.Id(c => c.ID);
    model.Id(c => c.TicketID).DefaultValue(Model.TicketID);
    model.Id(c => c.ReportPropertyID).DefaultValue(Model.ReportPropertyID);
    model.Field(c => c.PropertyName);
    model.Field(c => c.Amount);
})
```

Another way would be to handle the Grid's [edit event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit), check for inserts and set the values:

```
if (e.model.isNew()) {
    model.set("TicketID", $("#TicketID).val());  // hidden
    model.set("ReportPropertyID", $("#ReportPropertyID).val());  // hidden
}
```